# Symfony 4 Cache: No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony

i try to create a new project with symfony 4. The project folder is created via the default symfony 4 skelleton project `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton test`.

This is the output of the command:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton test
Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v3.4.4)
  - Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
Created project in test
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 89 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.0.70): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.6.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.7.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/webpack-encore-pack (v1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/link (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing fig/link-util (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/web-link (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/config (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v3.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/validator (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/serializer (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/inflector (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/property-info (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/property-access (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/serializer-pack (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-bundle (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bridge (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/class-loader (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/framework-bundle (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (3.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-code (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing ocramius/proxy-manager (2.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.13): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/migrations (v1.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/doctrine-bridge (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (1.8.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.5.14): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/orm-pack (v1.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/intl (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/form (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/expression-language (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/phpunit-bridge (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v2.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-bridge (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/web-profiler-bundle (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-bundle (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/stopwatch (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/profiler-pack (v1.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing easycorp/easy-log-handler (v1.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug-bundle (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug-pack (v1.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/asset (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v5.1.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dotenv (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/maker-bundle (v1.1.1): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Symfony operations: 20 recipes (2f96d696d346819d6ba100d95252f4e1)
  - Configuring symfony/flex (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/framework-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring doctrine/annotations (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/webpack-encore-pack (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (>=2.5): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/translation (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/security-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/monolog-bundle (>=3.1): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/routing (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/console (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (>=1.3.2): From auto-generated recipe
  - Configuring doctrine/doctrine-bundle (>=1.6): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (>=1.2): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/phpunit-bridge (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/web-profiler-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/twig-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring easycorp/easy-log-handler (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/debug-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring sensio/framework-extra-bundle (>=4.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/maker-bundle (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In Kernel.php line 865:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Warning: unlink(/home/fmk/Code/test/var/cache/dev/ContainerS8fduda.legacy):  
!!     No such file or directory                                                   
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!
```

Even when calling `php bin/console cache:clear` i get the same error:

```
php bin/console cache:clear

In Kernel.php line 865:

  Warning: unlink(/home/fmk/Code/test/var/cache/dev/ContainerS8fduda.legacy): No such file or directory
```

Even after deleting the files/folders in `var/cache` by hand and then trying to clear the cache again the error does not dissappear:

```
$ sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
$ php bin/console cache:clear

In Kernel.php line 865:

  Warning: unlink(/home/fmk/Code/test/var/cache/dev/ContainerS8fduda.legacy): No such file or directory
```

If i try to open a route in the application i get the same error as the one thrown when trying to call `cache:clear`.

If i try to create the missing file it throws a new error with a new file that can not be unlinked. These are the files that have come up so far:

- `var/cache/dev/ContainerS8fduda.legacy`
- `var/cache/de_`
- `var/cache/de~`
- `var/cache/de_/ContainerS8fduda.legacy`
- ...

I dont know what else to do to get the app running...

Has anyone a idea on what to do to fix this problem?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I created a shell script to create all the files that are "missing":

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf var/cache/*

mkdir var/cache/dev
touch var/cache/dev/ContainerToyerun.legacy
touch var/cache/dev/ContainerToyerun.legacy
touch var/cache/de~
mkdir var/cache/de_
touch var/cache/de_/ContainerToyerun.legacy
```

This lets enables me to make one request against the application but after that the `ContainerToyerun.legacy` file has a new name and i need to edit the script for a new request!

Answer (score 1):

Removing vendor/ and reinstalling composer will not solve the issue,
the issue is solved disabling xdebug.scream in your php.ini (or 20-xdebug.ini which symlinks to /etc/php/(YOUR PHP VERSION)/mods-available/xdebug.ini
)

Comment: Guys down voting the comment without reason doesn't improve the quality of the answer... please specify why this answer wasn't right from your point of view instead.

Comment: This answer is a good information because the script clear cache interrupt itself with a php  Warning: unlink( *name of the file * ): No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Symfony v3.4.4
Everything worked fine before this happened. `var/cache` directory permissions was **777** which means this was not file permission issue in my case. So I removed all composer components and install them again and it fixed my issue.

```
$ rm -rf vendor/* && composer install
```

Hope it will help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend read this website https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26158
The problema is due **xdebug.scream=1**