# Cache not properly clearing in Symfony 4.1.3, shows warning

Tags: symfony, caching, symfony4

Whenever I try to clear the cache via CLI (command `php bin/console c:c` (short for cache:clear)) I get the following output:

```
php.DEBUG: Warning: unlink(/app/var/cache/de_/ContainerWJOxaJf.legacy): No such file or directory 
{"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\SilencedErrorContext: 
{\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php\",\"line\":715,\"trace\":[{\"file\":\"/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php\",\"line\":541,\"function\":\"dumpContainer\",\"class\":\"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\HttpKernel\\\\Kernel\",\"type\":\"->\"}],\"count\":1})"} []
```

I've read I should try disabling the **xdebug.scream** (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233763)), but I'm fairly certain that won't fix the problem, as the cache really doesn't seem to get cleared. In the same question, it is mentioned (in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589505)) that I should remove the *vendor* directory and run `composer install` again. This also doesn't work.

Upon first clear, when no pre-existing cache is present, it just creates a */var/cache/dev/* directory. I don't get a warning and it shows the **[OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.** message. Any attempt after this does seem to temporarily create a */var/cache/de_/* directory, which gets deleted again. After this I get the above mentioned warning, but it also shows the **[OK] Cache for …** message after the warning. Still the cache itself doesn't seem to have been cleared.

I've also read that it may have something to do with the **.legacy** postfix and removing it might work, but I prefer not to tamper with this sort of stuff before knowing if it will actually work or not and what the consequences of such an action might be.

Has anyone come across this before and found a working solution?

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update**: just noticed this, but whenever a file changes and I clear the cache, I also don't get the warning, only when the cache remains unchanged. Also tried the disabling **xdebug.scream** method, but that didn't change anything. Overriding the Kernel to work with the `file_exists` does seem to get rid of the warning, but I'd rather steer clear of overriding the Kernel if possible...